# Парсинг строки

Tags: replace, javascript, синтаксический-анализ

Проблема в следующем:
Есть строка допустим со значением
    'привет мир страна привет люди привет'

и мне нужно в этой строке найти массив слов ['мир','страна','люди'] и обернуть их допустим в span`ы

```
text = text.replace /мир/g, "<span>мир</span>"
text = text.replace /люди/g, "<span>люди</span>"
```

можно конечно кучу раз писать такую конструкцию, заменяя каждое отдельное слово, но я думаю, что есть способ более элегантный, кто-нибудь подскажет как можно сделать лучше?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот регулярка, ничего сложного. Если в словах не будет спец символов (ну и если слов не очень много).

```
var words=['мир','страна','люди'],
    result='привет мир страна привет люди привет'.replace(new RegExp( '('+words.join('|')+')','g'),'<span>$1</span>')
```

> `"привет <span>мир</span> <span>страна</span> привет <span>люди</span> привет"`

Comment: вот, спасибо)) то что нужно, только вот у меня могут быть спец. символы

Comment: тогда предварительно экранируйте, я бы сделал сначала join с чем нить вроде IWIlLNEVeRBEHeRE потом бы экранировал спецсимволы regexp (**`.|()*+?`** и др)  и заменил бы IWIlLNEVeRBEHeRE на |

Comment: punctuation = ['{','}','(',')','[',']',';',':','.',',']

text = text.replace new RegExp('('+'\\\\'+punctuation.join('|'+'\\\\')+')', 'g'), "<span class='token punctuation'>$1</span>"

ну я так сделал) вроде работает))

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте как-то так:

```
var words =  ['мир','страна','люди'],
text = 'привет мир страна привет люди привет';

words.forEach(function (word) {
    text = text.replace(new RegExp(word, 'g'), "<span>"+word+"</span>");
});
```

Comment: да уже реализовал таким образом, но все равно мучают сомнения, что тут можно было бы как то без лишних циклов добиться нужного результата, но спасибо за ответ, чуть-чуть подожду, вдруг найдется лучше решение))

Comment: У вас соревнование с кем-то, кто меньше циклов сделат, тот и победил? Смотрите в первую очередь на понятность кода, а то в погоне за искусственно вводимыми условностями такого понаворотить можно, что и сам через пару дней не вспомнишь что и как оно делает, и вообще зачем было написано.